# entire sprite sheet showing in phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I can not figure out why my entire sprite sheet is showing in phaser. I think my code is correct, but apparently I am missing something. I tried specifying that the animation should start on pane 1, but when the game is loaded in to the browser all three panes show. Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much in advance!

### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Farm Game</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phaser.js"></script>
    <style>

        body{
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
            background:black;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

### JavaScript

```
var GameState={
  preload:function(){
      this.load.image('background', 'background.png');
      this.load.image('arrow', 'arrow.png');

      /*this.load.image('chicken', 'chicken.png');
      this.load.image('horse','horse.png');
      this.load.image('pig', 'pig.png');
      this.load.image('sheep','sheep3.png');*/

      this.load.image('chicken','chicken_spritesheet.png', 131,200,3);
      this.load.image('horse', 'horse_spritesheet.png', 212, 200, 3);
      this.load.image('pig', 'pig_spritesheet.png', 297,200,3);
      this.load.image('sheep', 'sheep_spritesheet.png', 244,200,3);



  },
     create: function() {

    //scaling options
    this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;

    //have the game centered horizontally
    this.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
    this.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;

    //create a sprite for the background
    this.background = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background')

    //group for animals

    var animalData=[

        {key:'chicken', text:'CHICKEN'},
        {key:'horse', text:'HORSE'},
        {key:'pig', text:'PIG'},
        {key:'sheep', text:'SHEEP'},

    ];


    this.animals=this.game.add.group();  

    var self= this;     
    var animal;

    animalData.forEach(function(element){

        animal = self.animals.create(-1000, self.game.world.centerY, element.key, 0);
        animal.customParams={text:element.key};
        animal.anchor.setTo(0.5);

        //animal animation

         animal.animations.add('animate', [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1], 3, false);

        animal.inputEnabled=true;
        animal.input.pixelPerfectClick=true;
        animal.events.onInputDown.add(self.animateAnimal,self);
    });

         this.currentAnimal=this.animals.next();
         this.currentAnimal.position.set(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.centerY);



    //left arrow
    this.leftArrow = this.game.add.sprite(60, this.game.world.centerY, 'arrow');
    this.leftArrow.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    this.leftArrow.scale.x = -1;
    this.leftArrow.customParams = {direction: -1};

    //left arrow allow user input
    this.leftArrow.inputEnabled = true;
    this.leftArrow.input.pixelPerfectClick = true;
    this.leftArrow.events.onInputDown.add(this.switchAnimal, this);

    //right arrow
    this.rightArrow = this.game.add.sprite(580, this.game.world.centerY, 'arrow');
    this.rightArrow.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    this.rightArrow.customParams = {direction: 1};

    //right arrow user input
    this.rightArrow.inputEnabled = true;
    this.rightArrow.input.pixelPerfectClick = true;
    this.rightArrow.events.onInputDown.add(this.switchAnimal, this);    

  },
  //this is executed multiple times per second
  update: function() {
  },

  animateAnimal: function(sprite, event) {
    sprite.play('animate');
  },

  switchAnimal: function(sprite, event) {

      if(this.isMoving){
          return false;
      }

      this.isMoving=true;

      var newAnimal, endX;

    if(sprite.customParams.direction >0){
       newAnimal= this.animals.next();
        newAnimal.x = -newAnimal.width/2;
        endX= 640 +this.currentAnimal.width/2;

    }else{

     newAnimal=this.animals.previous(); 
        newAnimal.x= 640 + newAnimal.width/2;
        endX= -this.currentAnimal.width/2;
    }
      var newAnimalMovement = this.game.add.tween(newAnimal);
      newAnimalMovement.to({x: this.game.world.centerX}, 1000);
      newAnimalMovement.onComplete.add(function(){
          this.isMoving=false;
      }, this);
      newAnimalMovement.start();

      var currentAnimalMovement= this.game.add.tween(this.currentAnimal);
      currentAnimalMovement.to({x:endX}, 1000);
      currentAnimalMovement.start();


      this.currentAnimal = newAnimal;
  }
  };







//initiate the Phaser framework
var game = new Phaser.Game(640, 360, Phaser.AUTO);

game.state.add('GameState', GameState);
game.state.start('GameState');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load a spritesheet you need to tell Phaser it's a spritesheet.

```
game.load.spritesheet('chicken','chicken_spritesheet.png', 131,200,3);
```

Then your animation should work as expected.

See the [official Load Spritesheet example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/loader/load-spritesheet) for a complete working sample.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped!